# How can I pass my model from my view to controller method using @Url.Action()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently, in my view I have this snippet:

```
@model List<Project.ViewModels.UsersViewModel> 
<a href="@Url.Action("FooBar", "Home", Model)">FooBar</a>
```

Where in my controller, I have a method with a signature like this:

```
public void FooBar(List<UsersViewModel> users)
```

The model is populated correctly in my view but I want to pass in the model as a parameter to that method inside my controller but it keeps passing in as 'null'. I'm not sure how to bypass this issue? I've tried Model, `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` and `RouteValueDictionary` as some other questions suggest but didn't work.

Comment: You cannot (and should not). Use a form to post the values (but if your not editing anything, what is the point - just send the ID of your model and get in again in the controller method

Comment: Well, the thing is I am trying to get the data from my model that I passed to view initially and then use it in the method above to export to a particular file type when the user presses that link.

Comment: So your know what the data is (your controller sent it to the view) so just get the data again in the `FooBar()` method (exactly as you did in the method that generated this view). And have a look at the `href` attribute of the link your generating to understand why parameter `users` will be `null`.

Comment: Ah okay, so you're saying, don't get the information from the view. Pass it from within the controller.

Comment: Yes. In order to pass back your collection you would need to generate a `href` attribute with `/Home/FoorBar?[0].somePropertyOfUser=someValue&[0].anotherPropertyOfUser=someValue&[1].somePropertyOfUser=anotherValue&....`. You would create a really ugly query string, and probably exceed the query string limit and throw an exception

Comment: Thank you. That was a good explanation! I got it working.